# VBA Macro - Unzip selective files without looping

Tags: vba, performance, unzip

We have a big zip file with hundreds of files. I have to pick a 15 sample files based on the given sample date.

For example, if the sample date is Jan 15th, then I would need the files created between Jan 8th till Jan 21st. I have tried extracting all files using Namespace and loop through but it is really time consuming. Searched through a lot of sites but couldn't find a way to extract only required files based on creation dates.

objWMIService works great to pick files with date attribute, but found that this will not work on zip files. Is there any solution similar to this for zip files?

```
Set colFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("SELECT * FROM CIM_DataFile WHERE Drive = 'C:'" & _
" AND Path = '\\p\\Rider\\' AND LastModified > '" & strDate & "'")
```

Any help on this will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try using the command line? Here's an example using 7zip https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/381630-extract-specific-7zip-files-based-on-date-modified

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but this module is a part of a standalone macro application which extracts data from multiple sources. This zip file is one such source. Is there any VBA code that can extract the files selectively based on the date?